# Django: import error in test

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I have a new project in django, without any test. I think that it should say that all is ok, because there are not tests when I try `python manage.py test`. Instead of that, I obtained this exit:

[shell screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ik4w.png)

Any one know why?

Comment: You have a new project ! Spend some time in building it instead of directly jumping into unit tests.

Comment: @nehemiah There are quite a few people who are considering "tests first" as best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Contain your problem into a sandbox by first switching to a python virtual environment instead of using Mac's full environment. From your errors, clearly modules could not be loaded due likely to wrong python path for packages unittest module is looking for. Following is a reference to run plain vanilla tests (rather no real tests!) on fresh django project in a virtual env. That should also help isolate your 'module not found' issues.

```
My-MAC [projects]$ python3.6 -m venv my_dj_pjt_venv
My-MAC [projects]$ cd my_dj_pjt_venv/
My-MAC [my_dj_pjt_venv]$ source bin/activate

(my_dj_pjt_venv) My-MAC [my_dj_pjt_venv]$ pip install django

(my_dj_pjt_venv) My-MAC [my_dj_pjt_venv]$ django-admin startproject my_new_project

(my_dj_pjt_venv) My-MAC [my_dj_pjt_venv]$ tree my_new_project
my_new_project
├── manage.py
└── my_new_project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py

1 directory, 5 files

(my_dj_pjt_venv) My-MAC [my_dj_pjt_venv]$ cd my_new_project/

(my_dj_pjt_venv) My-MAC [my_new_project]$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

The above shows a OK test due to no real test as you would expect for a fresh project.

Note: 'tree' command above is just for project display purposes. If needed, install with: brew install tree